# Weird SVG distortion with TornadoFX

Tags: svg, javafx, tornadofx

Having a strange issue while using SVGs in TornadoFX. I have a few SVGs strings stored in an enum I'm using as background images in my program. When I view the exact same SVG path in an online viewer, there is no distortion and it appears correctly:

[image: dumb globe svg]

but when I use the *same* path in TornadoFX as a `svgpath` node content, it appears like so:

[image: dumb globe but distorted]

Note the strange thinning of the lines in the top and bottom middle sections.

It's easier to see with the second svg:

Online viewer:

[image: dumb waves i'm not that great at this ok]

TornadoFX program:

[image: dumb waves but distorted]

I'm not quite sure what could be causing this. In everything else I view the SVGs in (web, illustrator) they appear fine, but as soon as I load them as a string in a `svgpath` node, they appear distorted.

I'm initializing them like this:

```
class mView : View() {

  override val root = stackpane {
    svgpath("M910.7,329.8a446.43,446.43,0,1,0,35,173.23A443.52,443.52.. etc") {
        addClass(SvgStyle)
    }
//..
}
```

Any ideas what would be causing this strange distortion? I'm pullin my hair out here.

**edit:** a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74mzctyp/) of the curvy SVGs

Answer (score 1):

TornadoFX doesn't affect the SVG rendering in any way, so I can't see any other explanation that this being a bug in the SVG rendering capabilities of JavaFX. Perhaps you're using a path expression not supported by JavaFX?

Comment: The JavaFX documentation says that they adhere to the W3 encoded string standard (https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html) which is what I'm using. :( That's a huge bummer if there's a bug with JavaFX SVG rendering.

Answer (score 0):

For the sphere, can you try setting the stroke on the SVGPath object as in the following example?

```
stackpane {
    svgpath("M107 380c40,-101 80,-102 120,-1m-1 -4c39,101 79,102 120,1m-1 4c39,-101 79,-101 120,-1m-1 -2c39,100 79,101 120,1", FillRule.EVEN_ODD) {
        fill = Color.WHITE
        stroke = Color.BLACK
        strokeWidth = 16.0;
    }
}
```

In the curves part of the question, can you post the full SVG path?  I suspect there's something in the path source telling JavaFX to render the thinner segments.

Comment: Setting the SVG with the options you have didn't change anything. I edited my original post with a Fiddle with the full SVG path.